# Building a countdown clock in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, countdown, seconds, minute, leading-zero

I'm building a countdown clock in JavaScript and am having trouble formatting it exactly how I want. Basically, I have a variable called totalTime which is initially set to the total number of seconds that the countdown will run for. Every second, this number decreases by 1, and I convert it into minutes and seconds for displaying on the page.

What's tripping me up is that I want to include a leading 0 on the number of minutes remaining, but only if the *initial* value of totalTime is 600 (10:00) or greater. So, if I set totalTime to 600, I want the countdown to display 10:00, 09:59, 09:58, etc. (note the leading 0); but if I set totalTime to 300, I want the countdown to display 5:00, 4:59, 4:58, etc.

Put another way, the leading 0 should appear based on the amount of time the countdown starts off with (the initial value of totalTime), *not* how much time is currently left (the current value of totalTime). How would I do this?

EDIT: here's the code I have currently: http://jsfiddle.net/JFYaq/

```
// Get the countdown element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// Set the total time in seconds
var totalTime = 600;

// Every second...
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    // Update the time remaining
    updateTime();

    // If time runs out, stop the countdown
    if(totalTime == -1){
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
}, 1000);

// Display the countdown
function displayTime(){
    // Determine the number of minutes and seconds remaining
    var minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
    var seconds = totalTime % 60;

    // Add a leading 0 to the number of seconds remaining if it's less than 10
    if (seconds < 10){
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    // Split the number of minutes into two strings
    var minutesString = minutes + "";
    var minutesChunks = minutesString.split("");

    // Split the number of seconds into two strings
    var secondsString = seconds + "";
    var secondsChunks = secondsString.split("");

    // If the total time is 10 minutes or greater...
    if (totalTime >= 600){
        // Add a leading 0 to the number of minutes remaining if it's less than 10
        if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        // Display the time remaining
        countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + minutesChunks[0] + "</span>" + "<span>" + minutesChunks[1] + "</span>" + ":" + "<span>" + secondsChunks[0] + "</span>" + "<span>" + secondsChunks[1] + "</span>";
    }
    // If the total time is less than 10 minutes...
    else {
        // Display the time remaining without a leading 0 on the number of minutes
        countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + minutes + "</span>" + ":" + "<span>" + secondsChunks[0] + "</span>" + "<span>" + secondsChunks[1] + "</span>"
    }        
}

// Update the time remaining
function updateTime(){
    displayTime();
    totalTime--;
}

// Start the countdown immediately on the initial pageload
updateTime();
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've written?

Comment: Updated with a link to JSFiddle (I couldn't get the code to format correctly within the post, for some reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JFYaq/1/**

Explanation:

To prefix a zero when necessary, the following function can be used:

```
function pad(n){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n : "0" + n;
}
```

Note `"" + n`. The `pad(n)` function will always return a string, which is useful for applying string methods.

The padding should always be used at the second counter. For the minute counter, store the original time in a variable, and check whether it exceeds 600 or not:

```
var original = 600;
function padMinute(n){
    return original >= 600 && n < 9 ? "0" + n : "" + n;
}
```

---

Relating to your code:

```
function displayTime(){
    var minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
    var seconds = totalTime % 60;

    minutes = "<span>" + padMinute(minutes).split("").join("</span><span>") + "</span>";
    seconds = "<span>" + pad(seconds).split("").join("</span><span>") + "</span>";

    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

`.split("")` turns splits the string in a list of characters. `.join("</span><span>")` is used to concatenate the set of string, adding `</span><span>` between every character. The The whole result is joined with `<span>` and `</span>` so that the final HTML is valid.

Execution model:

```
1. padMinute(minutes)                       "09"
2.             .split("")                   Array( "0" , "9" )
3.                   .join("</span><span>")
                                            "0</span><span>9"
4.                "<span>" + .. + "</span>" "<span>0</span><span>9<span>"
```

Comment: In your code, when you say `var original = totalTime;`, how come the value of `original` doesn't also decrease by 1 every second as totalTime does? I'm curious why this works.

Comment: In JavaScript, primitive values (Strings, Numbers, Booleans, `null` and `undefiend`) are copied when another variabel points to the variable which holds it. All other objects are passed by reference. So, `var a={b:2}, c=a; a.b=5; alert(c.b)` will show `5`.